# Sum of all diagonal elements from List<List<Integer>> using java streams?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

How to get sum of all diagonal elements in List of lists `List<List<Integer>>` using java streams?

Comment: does it form a square matrix? have you attempted something already? do update the question with more details.

Comment: Do not use a stream for that, just write a simple for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int diagonalSum(List<List<Integer>> matrix) {
    int n = matrix.size();
    return IntStream.range(0, n)
        .map(i -> i < matrix.get(i).size() ? matrix.get(i).get(i).intValue() : 0)
        .sum();
}
```

Just the same as a for loop: `IntStream.range` for a row&column index. One might add `.parallel()` though whether that is more efficient must be measured.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Joop, looks like I was trying in another direction, was trying with List streams but this one is clean.
So final one line solution for this is,

```
IntStream.range(0, test.size()).map(i -> test.get(i).get(i)).sum();
```